# Get transaction fee for charge result object (braintree credit card processing)

Tags: braintree

I would like to get the fee amount for a credit card transaction for braintree. Is there a way to get this?

```
$fee = $charge->transaction->serviceFeeAmount;
```

I was looking at:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/php#service_fee_amount

But this doesn't appear to be the fee I am looking for.

I am looking for the 2.9% + .30 fee. I know I can calculate it based on amount; but my first 50k is free and I don't want to change code when this switch happens.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

That fee is not part of the braintree api. The [reports](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/reporting/overview) would have that kind of information and I would contact support with any report related questions.

Comment: Which report specifically? I don't see that listed in any of my sandbox reports at the moment.

Comment: It's really going to be different on a merchant by merchant basis. I would reach out to support.

Comment: "**that** fee is not part of the braintree api" - does **that** mean "2.9% + .30 fee." ?

Comment: @wscourge that is correct, the "2.9% + .30" fee is not part of the api.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any chance if you have some insights as if it will be part of the API? I recently wrote to the support and got the response that it is not part of the api *at this moment*.

Comment: Unfortunately no, but we know it is something that our merchants are asking for, I'll make sure to relay this feedback.

Comment: Spongebob timecard: four years later...